# How to save data from datagridview to sql database without using a button

Tags: vb.net

I need to save data automatically without pressing any button from datagridview to sql database where admission number and names are retrieved from another table and insert score to another table.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        If cmbexam.Text = "CAT 1" And cmbpaper.Text = "Paper 1" Then

            sqlSTR = "SELECT AdmNo, Name, Class, Stream, Term, Exam, Subject, Paper, Limit, Score  FROM CT11 WHERE (AdmNo = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "') AND (Name = '" & row.Cells(1).Value & "')"
            ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

            If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                sqlSTR = "UPDATE CT11 SET AdmNo ='" & row.Cells(0).Value & "', Name ='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', Class ='" & cmbform.Text & "', Stream ='" & cmbstream.Text & "', Term ='" & cmbterm.Text & "', Exam ='" & cmbexam.Text & "', Subject ='" & cmbsubject.Text & "', Limit ='" & txtlimit.Text & "', Score ='" & row.Cells(2).Value & "'  WHERE (AdmNo = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "') AND (Name = '" & row.Cells(1).Value & "') AND (Class ='" & cmbform.Text & "') AND (Stream = '" & cmbstream.Text & "') AND (Term = '" & cmbterm.Text & "') AND (Exam = '" & cmbexam.Text & "') AND (Subject = '" & cmbsubject.Text & "')"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
            Else

                sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO CT11(AdmNo, Name, Class, Stream, Term, Exam, Subject, SP, Paper, Limit,Score) VALUES ('" & row.Cells(0).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', '" & cmbform.Text & "', '" & cmbstream.Text & "', '" & cmbterm.Text & "', '" & cmbexam.Text & "', '" & cmbsubject.Text & "', '" & CheckBox2.CheckState & "', 'Paper 1', '" & txtlimit.Text & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "')"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: What event would you like to use to trigger this action? A DataGridView has quite a few. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8#events

Comment: You don't save anything with a `Button`. A `Button` simply raises an event when it's clicked and you can handle that event. The code to handle the event is in the form. If you don;t want to save data when a `Button` is clicked then don't put your code in the `Click` event handler of a `Button`. Under what circumstances do you want the data saved? What event is raised under those circumstances? Put your code in the handler for that event.

Comment: I also strongly recommend that you learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET and write DAL code properly to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about Events:

> The concept of event-oriented programming is also well suited for the implementation of graphical user interfaces, where the events are mostly user actions, such as pressing a key or clicking a button. Another important field of application are computer simulations, which are set up in such a way that state changes are only triggered by events, and which in turn trigger events (see event-oriented simulation).

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)).

I think most developers use the [FocusLost-Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=netframework-4.8) to handle Datatransfer if you want to update your database immediately every time you change a value you can try the [CellValueChanged-Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.8).